# How to remove (unpublish) applications from the hosts start menu?

Tags: microsoft-virtual-pc

I have Windows 7 and a few virtual PCs (with the builtin Virtual PC feature) also running Windows 7.

Before I turned off automatic publishing of virtual applications a few such items were added to the host start menu. How can I remove them?

I tried the VBS script and also adding to the exclusion list as described on [this blog entry](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/windows_vpc/2009/11/02/publishing-virtual-applications-in-windows-virtual-pc/), but there is no effect.

Comment: So, the virtual apps were deployed to the host and you're trying to un-deploy them? Or have you un-deployed them but there are still remnants of them on the host?

Comment: @music2myear I installed apps on the guest, they were added to the hosts start menu. Then I turned off auto-publish, but that affects only future installs, so the "old" apps are still in the start menu of the host.